# How to simplify this F# code

Tags: f#, tuples, simplify

Isn't there a cleaner way to do this?

```
let Triplets = List.zip3 A B C
let T1 (x, _, _) = x
let T2 (_, x, _) = x
let T3 (_, _, x) = x
let Best = List.maxBy T3 Triplets
T1 Best,T2 Best // return to C# code
```

Comment: This is suited more to [CodeReview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @ildjarn No, unfortunately it is not. This code is a stripped down code snippet, there is no context here whatsoever, and there is no description about what the code does, this is considered "example code" which is off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: I'm fairly new here. Are you guys saying my question is not suited anywhere? I thought it was good style to strip down code for a post. As for  what the code does, I thought it would be fairly self evident that it merges 3 lists, finds a maximum and returns 2 elements of the maximum.

Comment: @JimLewis, you may want to tell us what the code is supposed to do (example input and expected output). Then, if the existing code isn't producing the expected result, that's the question for StackOverflow. If the code works but needs optimization, it is fine for CodeReview, but you also should tell what kind of optimization should be there: performance, readability, elimination of useless constructs, etc.

Comment: @JimLewis Stack Overflow wants code to be stripped down to a minimum, Code Review does not. You could post your *real, actual code*, with some context, on Code Review and ask for how it can be improved.

Answer (score 1):

The main improvement is to use pattern matching to extract data from tuples.

I would go with something along the following lines (shown as a function called `myFunc` which I've called with example data to check my understanding of your intention):

```
let A = [1; 2; 3]
let B = [4; 5; 6]
let C = [6; 7; 6]

let myFunc A B C =
    let triplets = List.zip3 A B C
    match List.maxBy (fun (_, _, x) -> x) triplets with
    | (a, b, _) -> (a, b)

let result = myFunc A B C //returns (2, 5)
```

You could shorten `myFunc` even more be piping the definition of `triplets` into `List.maxBy`, but at some cost of readability, like this:

```
let myFunc A B C =
    match List.zip3 A B C |> List.maxBy (fun (_, _, x) -> x) with
    | (a, b, _) -> (a, b)
```

phoog's suggestion would remove the matching:

```
let myFunc A B C =
    let (a, b, _) = List.zip3 A B C |> List.maxBy (fun (_, _, x) -> x)
    (a, b)
```

Comment: another option: `let (a, b, _) = List.maxBy (fun (_,_,x) -> x) triplets in a, b` -- in a multi-line example, replace the `in` keyword with a newline, of course.